# Going in object1.object2, writing instead of object 2 a variable

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to iterate an object inside another object.
ex:

```js
Object1
  stuff
  Object2
    stuff
```

I'm using a for loop to do so but I want to go to `Object2` without writing `Object1.Object2` but saving the name of the second object in a variable like:

```js
var something = Object2
Object.something
```

Actual code:

```js
for (var [key, value] of Object.entries(factory.cars.toyota)) {
  var type = typeof value;
  var array = Array.isArray(value);
  if (typeof value === "object" && array === false && value) {
    for (var [a, b] of Object.entries(factory.cars.toyota.key)){
      console.log(a);
    }
  }
}
```

The name of the object that I want is `infos` and it's saved in the `key` variable.

Is there a way to make what I did `toyota.key` possible?

car object:

```js
cars: {
    toyota: {
      id: 1,
      numberPlate: "S4IIPLE",
      broken: false,
      insurance: null,
      previousOwners: ["Mark", "Sebastian", "Carlos"],
      infos: {
        parketAt: "425 2nd Street",
        city: "San Francisco",
        state: "CA",
        postalCode: 94107,
      },
    },
```

Comment: Did you mean toyota[key]? You can't use dot notation if you use a variable as key name.

Comment: Yes, i meant that but didn't know that it existed.
Ty fellow programmer